# Clearing the Luigi Task Visualizer Cache

Tags: python, luigi

I'm testing a pipeline with Luigi and I've noticed strange caching behavior in the task visualizer. For one thing, tasks seem to stay in the cache for a set time, sometimes overlapping with tasks from a second run of the pipeline, causing clutter in the UI. I've also noticed that when two pipelines are run in succession it takes a while for tasks from the new pipeline to appear. Is there a way to manually reset the cache before each run? Is there a configuration variable that sets how long tasks are cached before they expire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the remove_delay setting for the scheduler. In your config file:

```
[scheduler]
remove_delay = 10
```

This applies to the scheduler so you need to restart luigid to enable it.

From the doc:

> Number of seconds to wait before removing a task that has no
>   stakeholders. Defaults to 600 (10 minutes).

From experience, stakeholders in that case seem to mean workers and upstream/downstream dependencies.

Comment: can `--remove-delay` be passed in as variable to a task?

Comment: Unfortunately not because it's a global parameter.